# c# windows 10 registry permissions

Tags: c#, windows

I have written a .NET 4 win form application in visual studio 10. It runs perfectly fine on windows 7 and windows server 2008 after being installed using innosetup. How ever when i install it on windows 10 it can't write to the registry "CurrentUser".

```
The error is Exception Info: System.UnauthorizedAccessException at Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey.Win32Error(Int32, System.String)
```

If i just copy the exe and supporting files to the windows 10 machine it runs perfectly fine with out needing  run as administrator.

What do i need to do to get windows 10 to trust the application after being installed?

Comment: try this thread may help you http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-update/net-framework-error/2cf75bfe-a312-4ea3-8df4-688f811ca4ef

Comment: thanks for the comment but I wrote the application its not some unknown malware.

Comment: Oh OK wait I will try to figure it out....